# Bitly API expand links

Tags: php, api, curl

I make bitly API PHP code

but not expand my links!

Response: http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_expand

This is my code:

```
$api_key = '*******';
$link = $_POST['link'];


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.bitly.com/v3/expand?login=*******&apiKey=' . $api_key . '&shortUrl=' . $link . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response);

echo $json->data->expand->long_url;
```

Comment: Show us the response.

Comment: Example Response
{
  "data": {
    "expand": [
      {
        "global_hash": "900913",
        "long_url": "http://google.com/",
        "short_url": "http://bit.ly/ze6poY",
        "user_hash": "ze6poY"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status_code": 200,
  "status_txt": "OK"
}

Comment: Don't include login or API key details in your post.

Comment: Yeah I know, but this is example api key :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you have in your comment is invalid. I've fixed it below. Pass in true to the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) function to make it return an array.

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);

{
    "data": {
        "expand": [
            {
                "global_hash": "900913",
                "long_url": "google.com/",
                "short_url": "bit.ly/ze6poY",
                "user_hash": "ze6poY"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status_code": 200,
    "status_txt": "OK"
}
```

Then get the `short_url` part.

```
echo $json['data']['expand'][0]['short_url'];
```

You have to access it like that because `expand` is an array.

Here is a demo using JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/6ujGB/

Comment: @user3492381 Sure, if you can be sure to accept the answer if it solve your problem. All you have to do is press the check-mark.